# copying row-values based on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with 2 pandas dataframes: `df` and `dfr`.

I'm trying to get the info from `dfr` to `df`, which I have done with this command:

```
df.update(
   pd.pivot_table(
      dfr,
      values='places_results.link',
      index=['search_parameters.location'],
      columns='labels',
      aggfunc='max'
   ).reset_index()
)
```

this turns `df`:

```
City      KWR1   KWR2   KWR3
Killeen
Killeen
Houston
Michigan
```

into this (With the links coming from `dfr`):

```
City      KWR1   KWR2   KWR3
Killeen   link1  link2  link3
Killeen
Houston
Michigan
```

The problem is that it doesn't copy those links to all other rows where `City = "Killeen"`

How can I make it copy the links 1 to 3 to every Killeen?